# JSON headers only show up on first line

Tags: javascript

I'm currently learning JavaScript and working on a project to do so. I'm currently stumped because a JSON file I'm currently working on doesn't look like the normal ones I deal with. Can anyone help me how I can use this data to show in my HTML file?

```
{
  "values": [
    [
      “name”,
      “age”,
      “location”
    ],
    [
      “Alice”,
      “28”,
      “Florida.”
    ]
]
}
```

I'm used to this format

```
[name:"Alice",age:"28",location:"Florida"]
[name:"Bob",age:"27",location:"Texas"]
```

Is there a way to transform it like that?

Thanks!

Comment: You have these wierd `“` and `”` in your code - it won't even run

Comment: "I'm used to this format" - what programming language is that? neither of those are JSON

Comment: That's what the API returns. Array 0 shows the header names. I'm learning javascript (which just happened to use JSON on it) so sorry if I don't get the terms right.

Comment: oh, right so the API returns the data in the first format, and you want to put it in a format that is not usable in javascript at all - did you want `[{name:"Alice",age:"28",location:"Florida"},{name:"Bob",age:"27",location:"Texas"}]`? that's usable

Comment: does the API **really** return those quote charcters that  aren't `"` ? i.e. `“name”`

Comment: Yes but the data that was fetched by the API is formatted in a way where the headers are in array 0 when I check the console.

Comment: sure, but does it really use `“name”` ... not `"name"` ... the former CAN be used, the latter can not (not easily)

Comment: Yup. When I use console.log on it, it shows "values: Array(277)[0 … 99]" and array 0 is where  "name" and "age" shows.

Comment: I'm directly asking about `“...”` vs `"..."` - can you see the difference? they are different characters, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a 2-dimensional array, where the first array contains **keys** and the second array a **value**.

Use below function to convert to desired output.

```js
const arr = [["name","age","location"],["Alice","28","Florida."]];

function arrToObject (arr){
    //assuming header
    var keys = arr[0];
    //vacate keys from main array
    var newArr = arr.slice(1, arr.length);

    var formatted = [],
    data = newArr,
    cols = keys,
    l = cols.length;
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            var d = data[i],
                    o = {};
            for (var j=0; j<l; j++)
                    o[cols[j]] = d[j];
            formatted.push(o);
    }
    return formatted;
}

console.log(arrToObject(arr));
```

BTW found the function from [here](https://gist.github.com/sarfarazansari/7e8ae05168b80b36016eb1c561a82f73)

Comment: you're assuming `“name”` was a typo and that the API actually uses `"name"`?

Comment: @Bravo Yes probably.

Comment: Just wondering, I got the data from an api, will it work? Do I need to add the data manually to const arr?

Comment: Pass the data you get from API to the function `arrToObject(dataFromAPI)`, I added to `const` for executable example here.

Comment: and what should I replace `const arr = with`?

Comment: @RudolphMusngi - that's the `values` property you get from the data you get from your API ? it'd have to be a string, because of those odd quote characters that JSON.parse would throw on

Comment: I get this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: arr.slice is not a function` Here's my current code https://jsfiddle.net/gt3zafbq/

Comment: `const arr = out.values` ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you don't have those weird quotes, so it's easy

```js
const resultData = {values: [["name","age","location"],["Alice","28","Florida."]]};

const [fields, ...values] = resultData.values

const result = values.map(item => Object.fromEntries(fields.map((field, index) => [field, item[index]])));

console.log(result);
```

Or

Like a boss ...

```js
const resultData = {values: [["name","age","location"],["Alice","28","Florida."]]};

const {values: [fields, ...data]} = resultData;

const result = data.map(item => Object.fromEntries(fields.map((field, index) => [field, item[index]])));

console.log(result);
```